# Would a 'while you were away' banner/section be beneficial for users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes when I log in I have to dig around a bit for interesting questions and answers. I know it's all subjective and there are filters etc, but it might be a cool idea to have a 'while you were gone' section at the top.

It could, for example, contain questions you've not see before that have high activity levels and match the top 3 tags associated with you.

Comment: That what we have [newsletters](http://stackexchange.com/newsletters) for.

Comment: Maybe this works on UX, but I doubt the usefulness on SO where there were tons of questions in the time I went for a coffee break.

Answer (score 2):

I like the idea, but I'm not sure how easily we could get StackExchange to change the base code to support this.  So it's more a technical issue than a UX one preventing it.

Comment: ah okay, thanks :) what's the best way to make this sort of suggestion to them?

Comment: @Chris, you could propose it as a "question" with tag of "feature-request" on the [main meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com).